# Adding a new blog to existing Rails4.0 Application at /blog subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, blogs, ruby-on-rails-4, octopress

I have to add a new blog to Rails 4.0 application. There is a good bit of insistence to add Wordpress as the blog. But I DON'T want to use subdomain, I want to make it www.mydomain.com/blog I read a lot of hassle which is involved in making that with wordpress.

Currently I am running my server on Heroku and soon might migrate to AWS. 
I read about heroku-wordpress with the reverse proxy to link /blog on server to Rails App but can this be extended to AWS setup ?

All other blog engines https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Blog_Engines do not say they work on Rails 4.

If we use one of the blog engine with Rails which is the one best suited for ease of maintaining blogs for a non tech team ?

I thought of Wordpress and Octopress as the top contenders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Octopress is a better option if you want to have full control of domain name (And more control in general), Wordpress needs less configuration though, both should work with rails 4